# LibreOffice Writer .... the ohm sign (Omega)

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, unicode, libreoffice

I am using *LibreOffice Writer* on Ubuntu 14.04 to do a class assignment and I need to use the **Ω** (Ohm sign, big letter omega) to show resistance.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find the sign anywhere.
Would anyone here happen to know how to print it or point me where to find it.
Some extensions maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Insert menu, Special character..., pick "Greek" in the right-hand drop-down, and you'll find Ω near the middle. Or just copy-and-paste the symbol in the previous sentence...

Answer (score 5):

On my Linux Mint 17 system I can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> (the unicode hex value) to get it in LibreOffice Writer.

I often find it easier to google for the unicode value of a symbol than to search for it in a table.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate... found it through the special character in Insert as @StephenKitt said

Answer (score 4):

I have a German keyboard layout, so it may differ for you if you use a different one. When you click on the keyboard icon (square with your keyboard's nationality written to it) in the panel and chose to view the key mapping (real translation might differ), you see which key corresponds with which character.

[image: >>image: German keyboard layout<<]

On my keyboard layout, the letter keys have special symbols assigned to them in 3rd (with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, lower right corner) or 4th (with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>, top right corner) level. If you now look at those keys, you'll find a **Ω** on the <kbd>Q</kbd> key in its 4th level.

That means in my case, I have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to easily and quickly type the Ω-sign.

Explore your own keyboard layout and find all the hidden gems! ;D